# Splitting a string over multiple lines with no extra whitespaces using Groovy?

Tags: string, groovy, string-concatenation

Lets say I have a long string, and putting it on one line would decrease the readability.

This is would be the solution and it works:

```
def string = "This is a very\
long string"
```

But what if im in a Method or an if Statement were the lines are already indented. Then i would have to put the second part of the string like this which isnt very readable.

```
if (condition) {
    def string = "This is a very\
long string"
}
```

How can i make the output look like this:

```
This is a very long string
```

With something like this:

```
if (condition) {
    def string = "This is a very\
                  long string"
}
```

Comment: Use `if (1) { println "This is a very " + "long string " + "and more" }` and line-wrap as you wish

Answer (score 1):

> How can i make the output look like this:
>
> This is a very long string

The code you show in the question is an idiomatic way to do it if you really need/want the literal definition to span lines in the source file without including a newline character in the literal:

```
def string = "This is a very \
long string"
```

You could also do something like this:

```
def string = '\
this is a \
very long string.'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would want to have the line breaks, there is `stripMargin` to
help with removal of leading white space (at least until groovy supports
the new multi-line string literals from Java).

But since you don't want the line breaks, I'd just "add" the strings.
This usually is a no-no, because strings are immutable in java and this
will create intermediate instances.  Yet then the compiler
*should* be able to optimize that, if you just add up string
literals (the (dynamic) groovy compiler 4.x *does not*).  But then again,
it might not matter.  And if you only want to pay once, make that
a `public static final String MY_CONST_STRING = ...` somewhere.

```
if (1) { 
    println "This is a very " + 
            "long string " + 
            "and more" 
}
```